# How to map() method output and not the method itself?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, stream

I'm new to Scala and created a infinite `Stream` of `int` and want to `map()` for each int `i`, the computed value `x`, which results from method `m(i) = x`. The point is, that I want the stream to actually stop when `x > 0`, AND I need the `i` which was used to compute the HIGHEST `x` of the list. However I'm struggling with this task, since I get an `UnsupportedOperationException empty.max`...

I tried using the code below, throwing the described exception. I also tried to create tuple out of `(i,m(i))`, but instead of actually applying `m(i)`, the method itself got mapped.

This is method `m`:

```
    def m(t: Int): Double = {
      //Some calculation...
    }
```

Ant I tried these options:

```
Stream.from(1).map(m(_)).takeWhile(_ > 0).toList.max
```

```
Stream.from(1).map((_,m(_))).takeWhile(_._2.apply(1) > 0).maxBy(_._2)
```

The second one shows this:

`missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$2: <error>) => m(x$2)) Stream.from(1).map((_,m(_))).takeWhile(_._2.apply(1) > 0).maxBy(_._2)`

How can I resolve this as short as possible? Thank you very much guys!

Comment: Try `Stream.from(1).map(i => i -> m(i)).takeWhile(_._2 > 0).maxBy(_._2)._._1` If you get a **UnsupportedOperationException empty.max** is because your stream was empty, that means that not a single element satisfied the `takeWhile` predicate, make sure your logic is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez, your solution is correct. However I can't mark a comment as accepted answer sorry for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> .map((_,m(_)))
> ```

This means `i => (i, j => m(j))`, not `i => (i, m(i))` which you want. So just write `map(i => (i, m(i)))` (or as Luis suggests, `i -> m(i)`) explicitly. I'd personally prefer braces for this lambda: `map { i => (i, m(i)) }`.

Comment: Thank you very much, yeah both solutions work thanks a lot! However, why does my expression mean this`i => (i, j => m(j))` ? Can you maybe explain this to me?

Comment: @kitaird It is because the way `_` desugars _(as a matter of opinion, I try to avoid it. Because it has caused me a lot of confusion)_. `_` means a lambda in that direct scope, thus `map((_,m(_)))` means `map(x1 => (x1, x2 => m(x2)))` because of the nesting. Also, `_` will never refer to same argument twice, it is one use only.